# 2x2 matrices and groups under multiplication

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let n be a positive integer.

(a) Let G be a set of real 2x2 matrices $A$ such that the $detA$ is a rational number of the form $m/n^t$ where $m$ and $t$ are nonnegative integers and $m\ne0$. Is G a group under multiplication?

(b) Same for $H$ of all real 2x2 matrices A such that $detA$ is of the form $n^t$ where $t\in \mathbb{Z}$?

I know the four defining properties of a group are closure, associativity, identity element, and inverse:

1. Closure - For every pair of elements $a$ and $b$, $a*b$ must be an element of the group. Should I use $GL(2,{\Bbb{R}})$ as a mental reference (it's a group under multiplication) to see if the properties of a group hold for both $G$ and $H$ in same way?
2. Associativity - For any three elements $a, b,$ and $c$, the equality $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$ must hold.  I know multiplication of 2x2 matrices is always associative so this holds.
3. Identity element - There is a group element $e$, the identity element, such that $a*e=e*a=a$ for any $a$ in the group.
4. Inverse - For every group element $a$, there is an element $b$, the inverse, such that $a*b=b*a=e$, where $e$ is the identity. Looks like the determinants for $G$ and $H$  are not equal to $0$, so they have an inverse.

The determinant forms are throwing me off a bit...can someone provide some guidance? Or a more formal way of proving this?

Comment: Is $t$ a **fixed** integer?

Comment: And what do you mean by using $GL(2,R)$ *"as an example"*?

Comment: You cannot use just one example to prove that a property holds for all examples!

Comment: The formal way to prove this is to start off with "Let A, B be in G. That means, by definition, that detA is [...] and detB is [...]. Then their product AB is also in G because its determinant is..."

Comment: No no I understand that, I'm just saying would it be helpful to look at GL(2,R) as an example of a group under multiplication where these properties hold (just for my own reference)...I wasn't going to use this group to actually prove these necessary properties of G and H here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it is not explicitly stated that $t$ is fixed, but I assume it is, just like for some $m$ (where it is 1 or greater).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** In determining closure and inverses, note that
$$
\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)\\
\det(A^{-1}) = 1/\det(A)
$$

Comment: For G's closure, would showing that $\frac{mx}{n^ty^s}=\frac{m}{n^t}\frac{x}{y^s}$ where $x$ is nonnegative, $y$ and $s$ are positive integers suffice?

Comment: Also, can't we simply say that inversion holds for G since the $detA$ is nonzero? (Using the fact that an n × n matrix has an inverse if and only if its determinant is nonzero)

Comment: Just because a matrix in $G$ has an inverse, doesn't mean that inverse is itself an element of $G$

Comment: For closure: what you need to check is whether that product can itself be written in the form $m/n^t$ for some choice of integers $m,n,t$